# Do we need to upload virtual env on github too?

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

This is my GitHub repo
https://github.com/imsaiful/backmyitem

I push from my local machine and pull the changes in Amazon EC2.
Earlier I have not added the virtual env file in my repo but now I have changed some file in admin directory which is containing in the virtual env. So should I go for to add the virtual env too on my GitHub or instead I change the same thing on my remote server manually?

Comment: Usually one adds the `requirements` file, etc. and then one constructs the environment with these requirements (and other specifics).

Answer (score 37, accepted):

As was mentioned in a comment it is standard to do this through a `requirements.txt` file instead of including the virtualenv itself.

You can easily generate this file with the following:
`pip freeze > requirements.txt` 
You can then install the virtualenv packages on the target machine with:
`pip install -r requirements.txt`

It is important to note that including the virtualenv will often not work at all as it may contain full paths for your local system. It is much better to use a `requirements.txt` file.

Comment: I think It will install virtual env but it will not add the changes which I have done in my local repo virtual env.

Comment: @imsaiful: what changes? Typically the idea of a venv is that you do not make (much) changes.

Comment: Are you referring to changes that you made to your virtualenv packages? If so then that can be quite challenging. Either find a way to not require changes to your packages(by overriding or updating or something) or branch the repository for the package, make your edits and manage updates yourself. Unfortunately Python is not necessarily expecting you to make changes to your virtualenv packages and does not have a simple solution for this.

Answer (score 7):

No - although the environment is 100% there, if someone else where to pull it down the path environment hasn't been exported not to mention Python version discrepancies will likely crop up.

The best thing to do is to create what is known as a `requirements.txt` file.

When you have created your environment, you can `pip install this` and `pip install that`. You'll start to built a number of project specific dependencies.

Once you start to build up a number of project dependencies I would then *freeze* your **local python environment** (analogoues to a package.json for node.js package dependency management). I would recommend doing the following in your terminal:

```
(local_python_environment) $ pip install django && pip freeze > requirements.txt

(local_python_environment) $ pip install requests && pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

That is to say, freeze your environment to a requirements.txt file every time a new dependency is installed.

Once a collaborator pulls down your project - they can then install a fresh python environment:

```
$ python3 -m venv local_python_environment
```

(* Please use Python 3 and not Python 2!)

And then activate that environment and install from your requirements.txt which you have included in your version control:

```
$ source local_python_environment/bin/activate

(local_python_environment) $ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Excluding your virtual environment is probably analogous to ignoring node_modules! :)

Comment: But I have changed some file in virtual virtual env /home/imsaiful/Desktop/local_repo/myvenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates directory. How to reflect this changes there?

Answer (score 2):

No Its not necessary to upload virtualenv file on github. and even some time when you push your code to github then it ignore python file only if add into ignore.

**Virtual Environment**
Basically  virtual environment is nothing but itis a tool that helps to keep dependencies required by different projects separate by creating isolated python virtual environments for them. This is one of the most important tools that most of the Python developers use. Apart from that you can add requirement.txt file into your project.

**Requirement.txt** 
It is file that tells us to which library and application are need to run this application. you can add requirement.txt file with this simple command.

```
 pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

After run this command all application and library add in this file. and if you make your project without activate any virtualenv then python automatically use system environment variable it will also add all the file that not necessary for your project.

Answer (score 0):

You should add the virtualenv in your gitignore. Infact github has a recommended format for python, which files should be added and which shouldn't

[Github recommendation for gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore)

Comment: But I do the changes in my virtual env file too in my development. IT is hard to do there in Amazon Ec2 same thing.I changes some code here in this dir /home/username/Desktop/local_repo/virtual_env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates